# How to learn Flutter with Node.js and MongoDB with realtime connection?

Tags: mongodb, flutter, express, sockets, nodes

I'm trying to build a realtime chat app with Flutter, Node.js and MongoDB. I am seeking some easy-to-read links or any documentation that explains how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these online courses:

- [Flutter](https://pro.academind.com/p/learn-flutter-dart-to-build-ios-android-apps-2020)
- [Node.js](https://pro.academind.com/p/nodejs-the-complete-guide-incl-mvc-rest-apis-graphql)
- [MongoDB](https://pro.academind.com/p/mongodb-the-complete-developer-s-guide-2020)

I know they seem quite expensive, but – judging by my personal experience – they're worth every cent. Trust me, Max is a great teacher ;)

Comment: Thank you, but does he put all the languages together in one?

Comment: @Teun No, they're separate courses. However, the Flutter course also covers [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com), which is quite suitable for building realtime chat applications (using the Realtime or Firestore database). I did that myself. If you'd like to learn Node.js and MongoDB, you might save a lot of money by getting the Academind Pro Membership for $19 per month. All courses are included and you can cancel it anytime you want.

Comment: He also had a YouTube video where you can learn flutter in 3 hours I followed that and it was worth the time. In that video he covered all the basics with Flutter. But now going full-stack with MongoDB and Node.js is quite hard, because there isn't a lot of data to find on the web. But really thank you for your recommendation!

Comment: Glad I could help! I watched the video on YouTube too before I bought the full course. Please consider accepting my answer to get me some reputation :) I‘m still new here...

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @NicolasEbeling: just a quick steer - unfortunately questions like this are off-topic. It's worth reading the Help Centre to understand what is on-topic (and thus what ideally should not be answered).